# Setting the style of the output in a text file

Tags: output-formatting, output, printing

My problem is related to `FormatType` of the `Output` of `Print[]`.

Look at this example code

```
i = 4;
Print["Try", "\tPippo : ", i, "\nPluto"]
```

The output is

[image]

If instead I send the output to another stream through

```
$Output = OpenWrite["demo.txt"]
```

and then I evaluate again the Print command, the output in the file “demo.txt” looks like the following

[image]

How can I save the text in the same style it appears in Mathematica?

For example, I want my text file to look like
[image]

Comment: does adding the option `FormatType -> OutputForm, that is, using `  `$Output = OpenWrite["demo2.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm]` give you what you need?

Comment: @kglr Yes!! Thank you!

Comment: I used FormatType -> OutputForm in the Print[] and it didn't work! thank you

Comment: apt45, i posted the comment as an answer.

Comment: FYI the reason this is not readily found in the `Print` documentation is that you normally would use `Write` for direct writing to  files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
$Output = OpenWrite["demo2.txt", FormatType -> OutputForm]
```

gives the desired result.

Comment: Is there a way to output `FullForm`. Just putting Value of option `FormatType -> FullForm` gives `"FormatType::ftype: Value of option FormatType -> FullForm is not valid."`.