# How to print all output in FullForm

Tags: output-formatting, output

How do I set all output to be printed/shown in `FullForm`. Setting the `FormatType` of the stream as in e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/164360/45020 does not work because `FullForm` does not seem to be a valid `FormatType` (`"FormatType::ftype: Value of option FormatType -> FullForm is not valid."`).

Comment: try `$Post = FullForm`?

Comment: consider also `$PrePrint`. For example, `keep = {Graphics, Graphics3D, MeshRegion, BoundaryMeshRegion, Image,   Image3D};
$PrePrint = If[MemberQ[keep, Head@#], #, FullForm@#] &`

Answer (score 5):

```
$Post = FullForm
```

*Example*

```
2 + 2 Sin[x + 7]
```

> Plus[2,Times[2,Sin[Plus[7,x]]]]

---

To reset:

```
$Post =.
```